AWS - How to pass DynamoDB scan data to C# lambda via Step Function?
I'm currently trying to learn AWS, and have a really simple thing here. This step function runs a DynamoDB scan and outputs it to a lambda written in C#.

The output of the Scan is this:

In my C# lambda, I have the default JSON serializer [assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))] up at the top, and I created an object for the data to serialize into:
public class DynamoDbScanResult
{
    public List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>> Items { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int ScannedCount { get; set; }
}

public async Task FunctionHandler(DynamoDbScanResult scanResult)
{
    ...
}

The step function runs successfully, but when printing out the scan result Count attribute, it's equal to 0. How can I obtain the scan results properly? I've also tried, as the parameter type,

ScanResponse
List<Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>>
Object
string (fails to serialize to string for some reason?)


I'm finding that the simplest lambda and serialization, with a message of { List: true } and the input being an object with just public bool List { get; set; }, is not working - it keeps printing out that the value of List is false which is the default value.
